# Loop through list with unknown value numbers in its rows

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array

I have this string:

```
tokens3="1,2,3****5,8,9,1,2,3****1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
string[] tokens4 = tokens3.Split(new string[] { "****" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

So I guess this gives me a listlike that:

> 1,2,3
>
> 5,8,9,1,2,3
>
> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

I want to loop through that list and get each value. How should I do that?
making it short: 
1-How to count tokens4 rows??
2-How to loop through each row's values ( I dont know how many values a row has)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the length of `tokens4` the same way as any array's length: `tokens4.Length`.

You can loop through `tokens4` using a standard `foreach` loop. From there you can split each list of tokens on a comma, if you want

```
foreach (string tokenList in tokens4)
{
    string[] tokens = tokenList.Split(',');
    // tokens.Length gives the number of tokens
    // You can loop through tokens using another loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do double splitting inside nested foreach.

```
    var tokens3 = "1,2,3****5,8,9,1,2,3****1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
    string[] tokens4 = tokens3.Split(new string[] { "****" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach(string token in tokens4)
    {
        var rows = token.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach(var row in rows)
        {
            // Here you have an access to the row value
            Console.WriteLine(row);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
tokens3="1,2,3****5,8,9,1,2,3****1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
string[] tokens4 = tokens3.Split(new string[] { "****" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach(string SplitedToken in tokens4)
{
      string[] Numbers = SplitedToken.Split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this regex:

```
[\*]+(\d*?)
```

With `ExplicitCapture` flag. See [demo on systemtextregularexpressions.com](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.split?p=W1wqXSsoXGQqPyk%3D&t=MSwyLDMqKioqNCw1LDgsOSwxLDIsMyoqKioxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOQ%3D%3D&op=4)

[image]